# Get and Set in C# Classes

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OrderManagementv1
{
    public class info
    {
        public string startPickTicket { get; set;}
        public string endPickTicket { get; set;}
        public string ordFile { get; set;}
        public int ordStartPage { get; set;}
        public int ordEndPage { get; set;}
        public string bolFile { get; set;}
        public int bolStartPage { get; set;}
        public int bolEndPage { get; set;}
        public string pickFile { get; set;}
        public int pickEndPage { get; set;}
        public string invFile { get; set;}
        public int invEndPage { get; set;}
        public info()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

and after that i do the following:

```
info i = new info();
i.startPickTicket = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
```

I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Maybe its something really simple. I dont understand. Please Help
Thank you

Comment: I expect `Value` is null, so you can't call `ToString()` on it. Check it in debug?

Comment: are sure that dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].Value.ToString(); has a value in it ?

Comment: Keep it paused in the debugger and hover over stuff until you find `null`.

Comment: odds are, either `dataGridView2`, `dataGridView2.CurrentRow`, or `dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells` is`null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue come from the Data you're trying to Get and not your entity.

You should take a look in dataGridView2.CurrentRow this is certainly 'null'. Or the cell doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Debugging tip: Split your huge statement into multiple small ones:

```
var row = dataGridView2.CurrentRow;
var cells = row.cells;
var cell = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0];
var selectedIndex = cell.ColumnIndex;
var selectedCell = cells[selectedIndex];
var selectedValue = selectedCell.Value;
i.startPickTicket = selectedValue.ToString();
```

The line in which the error occurs will reveal the cause of the problem.

Comment: You could also put a breakpoint on the line raising the exception and then use the debugging windows (Immediate, Watch...) to test the different chunks. It doesn't involve changing the code directly.

Comment: var cell = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0];

Comment: ^ thats where the new error is. It is definately not null, "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Answer (score 1):

This error means that something is set to `null`. In your code it could be any one of:

```
dataGridView2
dataGridView2.CurrentRow
dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex]
dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].Value
dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0]
```

If you refactor your code a little it will make it easier to find this error, as it will happen on a line that has less going on.

You can also code more defensively and add in checks that throw informative exceptions in order to get more useful exceptions at run time. Using `Convert.ToString` rather than `.ToString()` will make the code tolerant to the cell's `Value` being null.

```
if (dataGridView2 == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The grid is null");

if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Length == 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No cells are selected in the grid");

if (dataGridView2.CurrentRow == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The grid has no current row");

var cell = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0]
var currentRowCell = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex];

info i = new info();
i.startPickTicket = Convert.ToString(currentRowCell.Value);
```